# Rearranging array elements

Tags: c++, c, arrays

Not sure if it is a duplicate. Given a data structure having first `N` integers and next `N` chars. `A = i1 i2 i3 ... iN c1 c2 c3 ... cN`. I need an in-place algorithm to rearrange the elements as `A = i1 c1 i2 c2 ... iN cN`.

Comment: Almost duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777184/rotate-2d-rectangular-array-in-place/3777262

Comment: What is the question?  Surely we are not going to write all your code for you.  Do you have any code to share?  Have you run into any specific problems that we can help you with?

Comment: btw:  How does a C/C++ array hold both chars and ints, without a lot of typecasting?

Comment: @abelenky: i tried outputting the values to another array but couldnt think of an in-place approach.

Comment: @yadab: No, this will transform `i1 i2 i3 ... iN c1 c2 c3 ... cN` to `c1 c2 c3 ... cN i1 i2 i3 ... iN`.

Comment: @ybungalobill: I am sorry, I deleted that my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is equivalent to transposing a 2xN matrix in-place. You can read the theory here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition

Maybe in the special case of 2xN matrix a simpler algorithm exists, however I can't think of any. The general idea is to follow the cycles of the permutation.

Comment: Can you not generate those cycles using http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/?

Comment: @André: No. What's the connection?

Comment: A simpler algorithm for 2xN exists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777901/array-interleaving-problem/

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be 3 problems in this question.

1. Insert both types of items in the same list. There are several ways to do this, but it won't be pretty.
2. [partition](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partition/) the data to separate chars and ints.
3. [sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) each partition to order chars and order ints.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a standard sort problem.

All you need is a good comparison function, then use `qsort`.

Are you familiar with `qsort`?
Have you created any piece of a comparison function you can share with us?

**Edit** 
As commentors have pointed out, `qsort`, `std::sort`, and other similar routines need objects of identical size.  Since the question calls for an array of ints and chars, which are of different sizes and is not strictly possible in C/C++, more information is needed.

Exactly how is this array declared?  How big are the ints and how big are the chars?  Does the existence of chars imply that N is limited to 255?

Once again, some code would *really* help.

Comment: Why use a C library when there are C++ versions? std::sort()

Comment: You need to maintain the order in which the ints/chars appear, so sorting won't work.

Comment: Any stable sort (mergeSort, insertionSort, bubbleSort) will work, but qsort (quickSort) is not stable, so it won't work for what OP wants.